# Adding students to rows in a classroom

Tags: functional-programming, scala

I'm learning Scala and functional programming. Can I make it more functional?

```
class Student(val firstname: String, val lastname: String) {
  override def toString: String = firstname + " " + lastname
}
class ClassRoom {
  var rows: List[Array[Student]] = List[Array[Student]]()
  var total: Int = _
  def addRow(row: Array[Student]) = {
    rows = row :: rows
    total += row.length
  }
  def print = rows.foreach(r => r.foreach(println))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of small things to start.

```
var rows: List[Array[Student]] = List[Array[Student]]()
```

This line can be simplified slightly by doing this instead:

```
var rows: List[Array[Student]] = List.empty
```

Unless you are caching the `total` for performance reasons, you could calculate it as needed with something like this:

```
def total: Int = rows.map(_.length).sum
```

That would simplify `addRow()` to this:

```
def addRow(row: Array[Student]) = rows = row :: rows
```

---

One of the tenets of functional programming is the use of immutable data. `ClassRoom` is not very functional from this perspective: both `rows` and `total` are mutable. If you wanted to take a pure functional approach, all members would be `val` and functions like `addRow()` would return a new `ClassRoom` instead of modifying itself. For example:

```
class ClassRoom(val rows: List[Array[Student]]) {
  def total: Int = rows.map(_.length).sum
  def addRow(row: Array[Student]) = new ClassRoom(row :: rows)
  def print = rows.foreach(_ foreach println)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a case classes as replacement of the normal Student and room class:

```
 case class Student(firstname: String, lastname: String) 
 case class ClassRoom(rows: List[Array[Student]])
```

Case classes are:

1. Immutable by default
2. Generate toString, hashCode & equal by default. No typing needed
3. Incredible compact syntax. I'm not aware of anything shorter
4. Fit well with functional style

Read more on: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/107

For more functional sytle, try to avoid empty / null references. Instead do this:

1. Mutate only parameter
2. Avoid side effects in functions to keep them pure.
3. Combine simple functions to form complex functions.

1) Mutate only parameter:

Instead of changing a variable, you only modify a parameter and return
the modified parameter. This is thread-safe as long as all used local fields
and data-structures are immutable (val) and the function is without side-effects.

2) Side effects are:

1. Reassigning a variable
2. Modifying a data structure in place
3. Setting a field on an object (case classes have no setter!)
4. Throwing an exception or halting with an error
5. Printing to the console or reading user input
6. Reading from or writing to a file
7. Drawing on the screen

Essentially, functional programming has the idea of a "pure" core that is a bunch of pure functions only mutating parameters without any side effects and a very thin access layer, sometimes called IO layer of impure functions handling all sorts of IO like file reading or user interface interaction.

3) Combine simple functions.

Simple function are, for instance, a sum or size function. Calculating 
the let's say average is the sum off all values divided by the number
of all elements. A functional style would be to nest the the sum
function inside the average function but keeping both pure. For instance:

```
 def avg(values: Array[Double], nrElements): Double = values.sum / nrElements
```

In this case, sum is a standard function of Scakla Array. This function is pure
because it has no mutable fields, it only mutatates parameters and it has no side other side effects.

Back to your example, if you want to interact with your Student and Room case class, pass either one of them, or both to a function do whatever you want to do
by mutating the classes / collections by using only immutable fields.

So, beginning with the calculation of the total numbers of students, you make
a function that takes the collection as parameter calculates the total number
and returns it. Like so:

```
  def total(c : ClassRoom)= c.rows.map(_.length).sum
```

For performance, and sum over lists always suck in terms of performance, use lazy val that means, the function gets called only if the field gets accessed the first time and then stores the value in it. In other words, you write:

```
  val s1 = Student("Linus", "T.")
  val s2 = Student("Bill", "G.") 
  val s3 = Student("Larry", "E.")
  val r1 = Array(s1)
  val r2 = Array(s2,s3)

  val prog101 = ClassRoom(List(r1,r2))

lazy val size = total(prog101)
```

Let's say you want to print the class one by one student. This is an impure fuction because it prints to the system console. Ok in this case you pass 
the class to function like so:

```
   //@IMPURE: prints to console
   def printClass(c : ClassRoom) = c.rows.flatten.foreach(println)
```

Which you use in a familiar way:

```
 printClass(prog101)
```

Now, lets say you want to print out the class size. in this case, you can 
re-use the size function we already know like so:

```
   def printClassSize(c : ClassRoom) = println(total(c))
```

which you can use, just like the previous function:

```
  printClassSize(prog101)
```

So what are the lessons learned?

1. Functional programing uses immutable data-structures
2. Functions should be simple and pure
3. Complex functions are built from simple functions

Full source code of the example is on github:

https://gist.github.com/marvin-hansen/5802829

Additional material worth reading:

1) eBook google: "Functional Programming in Scala" (Manning publisher)

2) FREE coursera material, google: "Functional Programming Principles in Scala"

Hope that helps
m

Answer (score 0):

1. The Student class is better implemented as a case class
2. The addRow method should return another instance of the ClassRoom class
3. Use foldLeft (or another higher-order function like map) to compute the total
4. Use toString instead of .foreach(println) to avoid side-effects...
5. You can use companion object for convenient purposes

Here it is:

```
case class Student(fname: String, lname: String)

class ClassRoom(val rows: List[List[Student]]) {
  def addRow(row: List[Student]) = ClassRoom(row :: rows)
  def total = rows.foldLeft(0)( _ + _.length)
  override def toString = rows.map(_.mkString("\n")).mkString("\n")
}

object ClassRoom {
  def apply(rows: List[List[Student]]) = new ClassRoom(rows)
}
```